# Cannot find package under GOPATH

Tags: go, gopath

I am trying to install the dependencies of my project with `glide`but unfortunately it fails with the following message:

```
main.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/arschles/go-in-5-minutes/episode13/models" in any of:
    /Users/theo/go-workspace/src/github.com/thitami/go-in-5-minutes/episode13/vendor/github.com/arschles/go-in-5-minutes/episode13/models (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/github.com/arschles/go-in-5-minutes/episode13/models (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/theo/go-workspace/src/github.com/arschles/go-in-5-minutes/episode13/models (from $GOPATH)
```

Running a `go env`, this is my env variables of interest:

```
GOPATH="/Users/theo/go-workspace"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec"
```

Please be advised that I am `zsh` and I am exporting the `GOPATH` inside the `.zshrc` file like this:

```
export GOPATH=HOME/go-workspace
```

Any ideas are appreciated

*** UPDATE ***

As requested this is the piece of code with the call to the `models` package:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    "github.com/arschles/go-in-5-minutes/episode13/models"
    _ "github.com/mxk/go-sqlite/sqlite3"
)
```

Comment: Is the package at any of those locations? I'm not familiar with glide but it sounds like you need to run `go get` first.

Comment: No, that is the issue. The package is not there.
Glide is a vendor package manager, such as composer for PHP.

Comment: What command are you running when glide gives you that error?

Comment: `glide install`, which installs all the dependencies.

`go get` did the job but I am wondering whether the message thrown indicated that there is false setup in my machine.

Comment: Hi, can you share your code? It looks strange that your package `github.com/thitami/go-in-5-minutes/episode13/models` is looking for `github.com/arschles/go-in-5-minutes/episode13/models`

Comment: @RaimondasKazlauskas Updated my question with the `import`

Comment: doesn't glide install the packages to the vendor folder location? That would mean you need to set your gopath to where the vender directory is..normally the top level of your project. https://github.com/Masterminds/glide

Comment: @reticentroot That is correct. Packages go under vendor folder.
Thing is that this is a series of screencasts and respective number of "projects", so shall I be resetting the GOPATH in every case?

Comment: I see. That sheds some light @reticentroot. Many thanks!

Comment: @thitami moved this to an answer so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set the gopath once and you'll have to reset it every time you change packages. Think of it as a virtualenv. One way around it is to install the packages global or by using something like gvm